# Sending an escaped array of string to a piped process

Tags: powershell

I have a bash linux script:

`echo -e '\x55\x55\xaa\xaa\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x50' | netcat -w 2 192.168.10.187 8000`

Now I am trying to convert it to PowerShell, but I'm not sure what the syntax of echo is for this line of characters.

When I just do:
`echo '\x55\x55\xaa\xaa\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x50' | & .\nc -w 2 192.168.10.187 8000`

I get no result, but I'm not sure if the character string even gets piped into `nc` or that it's the wrong character string.

Comment: If you're concerned with the stuff prior to the pipe, remove everything after the pipe to check the output. `echo '\x55\x55\xaa\xaa\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x50'`

Comment: Well they are just bytes so it's hard to verify, then I would need it to be formatted to text to be able to read it.

Answer (score 1):

To check the bytes use the Format-Hex cmdlet.

```
PS > $bytes = [Byte[]] (0x55,0x55,0xaa,0xaa,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x50)
PS > $bytes | Format-Hex
           Path:
           00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F
00000000   55 55 AA AA 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 50              UUªª.......P
```

Comment: This answers only part of the question: the byte array needs to be converted to a string for output to `nc`, using a method such as given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41762760/convert-hex-to-ascii-in-powershell) (the new answers are better than those in the duplicate link).

Comment: @AFH Ack, tried `[System.Text.Encoding]::ANSI.GetString($bytes)|Format-Hex` but that cripples values above `0x7F`

Comment: I've tried a lot of different conversions and none of them works for characters with the top bit set. At the moment I can see two ways to do what the questioner wants: (1) use a hex editor (or use `bash` in Linux or one of its Windows incarnations) to create the `nc` input string in a file and take input from there, instead of piping a string created on the fly within PowerShell; (2) create the string on the fly with a Windows port of the Linux `/bin/echo` command, though some are Bourne-compatible and do not support hex, so octal `\125\252` may be needed instead of `\x55\xaa`, etc.

Comment: @AFH In the meantime I found a [Q&A on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24708859/output-binary-data-on-powershell-pipeline) which states that powerShell always applies an encoding to what is piped which mangles the bytes

Comment: ... Which is a very good reason for taking input from a file, not a pipe, as in my option (1).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it can't be done with Powershell due to output limitations, so I wrote a tiny C# app:

```
        using (var stdout = Console.OpenStandardOutput())
        {
            var buffer = new Byte[]
            {
                0x55,
                0x55,
                0xaa,
                0xaa,
                0x00,
                0x00,
                0x00,
                0x00,
                0x00,
                0x00,
                0x00,
                0x50
            };
            stdout.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }
```